If $a,b,c$ are the sides of triangle of circumradius $R$ and $x>2R$, is there always a triangle with sides $\frac{1}{a+x},\frac{1}{b+x},\frac{1}{c+x}$
If $a,b,c$ are the sides of non-degenerate triangle of circumradius $R$ and $x>2R$, is there always a triangle with sides $\displaystyle \frac{1}{a+x},\frac{1}{b+x},\frac{1}{c+x}$? More precisely, experimental data shows that
$$
\frac{x-2R}{x^2+2Rx} < \frac{1}{a + x} + \frac{1}{b + x} - \frac{1}{c + x} <
\frac{1}{x}. \tag 1
$$
Can $(1)$ be proved? While trying to prove the above inequality, I was able to prove a similar looking inequality
$$
0 \le \frac{a}{a+x} + \frac{b}{b+x} - \frac{c}{c+x} \le \frac{4}{x+2} \tag 2
$$
which holds for all $x>0$.

A slightly related question here.

WLOG, we can assume that:
$$a\le b \le c \le 2R \lt x\tag{1}$$
...because the longest side of triangle cannot be longer than the diameter of the circumscribed circle. This means that:
$$\frac{1}{a+x}\ge\frac{1}{b+x}\ge\frac{1}{c+x}\tag{2}$$
If $\frac{1}{a+x}$, $\frac{1}{b+x}$ and $\frac{1}{c+x}$ are to form a triangle one has to show that:
$$\frac{1}{a+x}\lt\frac{1}{b+x}+\frac{1}{c+x}\tag{3}$$
$$(b+x)(c+x)<(a+x)(c+x) + (a+x)(b+x)$$
$$bc + (b+c)x+ x^2<ac + (a+c)x+x^2+ab+(a+b)x+x^2$$
$$bc + (b+c)x<ac + (2a+b+c)x+ab+x^2$$
$$bc < ac + 2ax+ab+x^2$$
...which is obviously true according to (1) because $b,c<x\implies bc < x^2$
